# Availability of built-in models in loopback4

Tags: loopback4

Is built-in models are available in loopback4 like loopback3(ACL, AccessToke, User etc). If no, how to create a user model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Extracting the answer from [LoopBack Slack channel](https://join.slack.com/t/loopbackio/shared_invite/zt-8lbow73r-SKAKz61Vdao%7E_rGf91pcsw).*

LB4 doesn’t have built-in models. If you are looking for the access control implementation in LB4, we have  a migration guide in https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/migration-auth-access-control-example.html.

And the corresponding example in
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/tree/master/examples/access-control-migration